# Cannot configure sonarqube with Jenkins using jcasc

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jcasc

I am wondering if the support for some plugings like sonarqube uding jcasc have be abandoned, because I have been trying to using this settings

```
unclassified:
  sonarglobalconfiguration:
    buildWrapperEnabled: true
    installations:
      - name: sonarqube
        serverUrl: https://sonarqube
        credentialsId: token-sonarqube
        serverAuthenticationToken: "" 
        additionalAnalysisProperties:
        additionalProperties:
        mojoVersion:
        triggers:
          envVar:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
```

I get this error:

```
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: Invalid configuration elements for type class jenkins.model.GlobalConfigurationCategory$Unclassified : sonarGlobalConfiguration.
Available attributes : administrativeMonitorsConfiguration, artifactManager, buildDiscarders, buildStepOperation, builtInNode, casCGlobalConfig, defaultDisplayUrlProvider, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView, email-ext, enrichedSummaryConfig, envVarsFilter, fingerprints, gitHubConfiguration, gitHubPluginConfig, globalDefaultFlowDurabilityLevel, globalLibraries, globalTimeOutConfiguration, injectionConfig, junitTestResultStorage, location, mailer, myView, nodeProperties, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, quietPeriod, resourceRoot, scmGit, scmRetryCount, shell, timestamper, usageStatistics, viewsTabBar
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator
```

Any help or point in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: It's generally better and more straightforward to use maven to run SonarQube since you don't have to worry about outdated plugins. Any reason you might be going for this approach?

Comment: Thanks for responding,  I'm not sure I'm familiar with that method,  but I finally figured it out, I haven't installed the sonarqube scanner plugin for Jenkins yet. So I'm just getting introduced to Jenkins Configuration As Code.